# Искажение цвета в webgl

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, glsl

Cоздаю рисовалку.

Рисую на canvas с помощью webgl множество квадратов с маской и альфой.

При альфе > 0.1 проблема незаметна. Но стоит сделать альфу чуть меньше - появляется неприятное искажение цвета.

Я использую классическое смешивание

`gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

результат для большой альфы:

[image: альфа >0.5]

A вот результат при альфе [0..0.01]:

[image: альфа <0.01]

Думал, что это как-то связано с точностью, но между mediump/highp float разницы нет.

Помогите, как это фиксить?
[вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex_PXX/u3hb784d/)